# Download Data from JSON $ajax

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download data off a server and return the data but, the function I made does not seem to return the downloaded data. It keeps returning the promise, can someone help me out?

Here is the output on console:

```
part3-main.js:9 data {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
part3-application.js:55 Downloading Data
part3-application.js:56 Downloaded Data
part3-application.js:58 parsee (994) [{…},...]
```

```
var getAndParseData = function(){
  var download_data = $.ajax({
    url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MUSA611-CPLN692-spring2020/datasets/master/json/philadelphia-crime-snippet.json"
  })
  .done(function(data){
    console.log('Downloading Data');
    console.log('Downloaded Data');
    parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('parsee', parsed_data);
    return parsed_data;
  });
  console.log(download_data);
  return download_data;
};
```

Comment: `getAndParseData` will always return a `Promise` object (this is how it is supposed to work). You have to place all your logic inside the `function(data)` callback passed to the `done` call.

Comment: `$.ajax()` will return promise. you can perform all needed operation inside `done` or you can use `getAndParseData.then(d => your operation)` outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.ajax` returns a Promise, you must wait for it to resolve before you start working on the data it returns. You can do this inside `.done()`:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MUSA611-CPLN692-spring2020/datasets/master/json/philadelphia-crime-snippet.json"
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    let results = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Success!', data)
    // do stuff with results here
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    console.log('something went wrong', error);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ajax call returns a promise you need a way to resolve that. As an alternative to the callback approach provided above you can use the async/await. Not much you need to change from your code structure.

Note: you will need a way to handle errors

```js
var getAndParseData = async function(){
  var download_data = await $.ajax({
    url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MUSA611-CPLN692-spring2020/datasets/master/json/philadelphia-crime-snippet.json"
  })
  
  console.log(download_data)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```